# PHP templating systems

Tags: php, templates

I currently use Smarty 2.26 for all my sites, I am planning to to a PHP 5 template system

There are quite a few options
Smarty3
Dwoo
Twig and more

I am looking for something light weight and speed is important, there are many blogs out there that equally rated all of the 3 above.

Which framework should I stick with.

Comment: "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." You may receive better responses on [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've built your site around smarty 2 then it's probably worth moving to smarty 3, that way you won't have as big a job to change your code. Also smarty 3 has lots of new speed improvements so it's definetly a strong contender.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want speed and light weight, php IS a templating engine. So why bother with a cumbersome templating engine on top of it?